# How to write a block to return value from one class to another?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift-block

I searched many questions here but seems no one is for the below question.

---

I am trying to create a block completion in Swift.

**This is an optional variable closure in class X.**

```
var onLogCompletion:((_ logThing:String) -> ())?
```

**This is the function in class X.**

```
func printerCompletion(currentLog:String) -> Void {
    //This is giving me an error:
    //Cannot call value of non-function type '((String) -> ())?'
    !(onLogCompletion(currentLog))
}
```

**From class X, I want to call the function like this.**

```
printerCompletion("New Log")
```

**In a View Controller, I want to do stuff like this.**

```
let objX = X()
objX.onLogCompletionm { (log) in 
    print(log)
}
```

> That should print `New Log` in a View Controller file.

**I have experience of doing this in Obj-C but not with Swift.**

Please help to solve this and also if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Can you show where you are calling this `printerCompletion` because if you are calling it from the `init` then your `onLogCompletionm` is not set and you are force wrapping when you call completion thats the reason you are getting nil, show more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may this help you:

```
    var onLogCompletion:((_ logThing:String) -> ())? = nil


     func printerCompletion(currentLog:String) -> Void {
            self.onLogCompletion!(currentLog)
        }

     self.onLogCompletion  =  { (log) in
            print(log)
        }
```

you need to define block before  calling of block other wise it will be nil

```
    objX.onLogCompletionm  = { (log) in
                            print(log)
                    }

   printerCompletion(currentLog: "New Log")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that gave me an error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Is there any more decent way of doing this in Swift?

Comment: As soon as I set `nil` for the closure, it works. I also require to checks `    func printerCompletion(currentLog:String) -> Void {
        if onLogCompletion != nil {
            onLogCompletion!(currentLog)
        }        
    }` to fix the error.

Comment: can you explain that which kind of that?